# Problem outputting text into a text file from c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am having problems getting the output of this event to go to a text file, I think it might be something to do with the "File" value

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var file = File.AppendText(@"c:\output.txt");

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"c:\filename.txt");
            Regex reg = new Regex(@"\w\:(.(?!\:))+");
            List<string> parsedStrings = new List<string>();
            while (sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                parsedStrings.Add(reg.Match(sr.ReadLine()).Value);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code that is actually using the "file" variable to output any text?  I see code that reads in the input file, but there is no corresponding write to the output file.

Comment: @Matt Hamsmith No :/, I need to output the list to a file

Answer (score 1):

`File.AppendText(@"c:\output.txt");` returns a `StreamWriter`. I don't see where you are writing to this. You are just adding items to a `List<String>`. Looks like you forgot to call `file.Write()` call.

You don't need a `List<String>` in that case.

you can do

```
while (sr.EndOfStream)
{
    file.WriteLine(reg.Match(sr.ReadLine()).Value);
}
```

or if you need the `List<String>`

then you can try

```
parsedStrings.ForEach(s => file.WriteLine(s));
```

after the while loop.

Comment: I would like to output these items in the list to a file

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"c:\output.txt")) 
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"c:\filename.txt");
    Regex reg = new Regex(@"\w\:(.(?!\:))+");

    while (sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(reg.Match(sr.ReadLine()).Value);
        }
}
```